# How can I fill all padding bytes of a non-compact struct with a specific value?

Tags: c

We know that for alignment reason, a struct can have internal padding bytes.

How can I fill all padding bytes of a non-compact struct with a specific value?  In other word, consider the following code segment:

```
struct Foo;

// Is that possible to implement pad_Foo() function? If Yes, How?
void pad_Foo(struct Foo *pFoo_x, char pad_byte);

void bar(struct Foo *pFoo_x, int fd, char pad_byte)
{
    // reading in *pFoo_x from a file.
    // It may get some garbage padding bytes.
    read(fd, pFoo_x, sizeof(struct Foo));

    pad_Foo(&x, pad_byte);
}
```

Is it possible to implement pad_Foo() function, and if the answer is yes, how?

Comment: You do not have any control over the padding bytes in a struct other than to issue a `#pragma pack` to minimize or eliminate it. Other than that type of influence, the rest is up to the compiler.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? (BTW: the answer is no)

Comment: You could `calloc(sizeof(struct foo), pad_byte)` and then set your fields accordingly

Comment: @TheophileDano Well, actually not. From the standard: "51) Thus, for example, structure assignment need not copy any padding bits."

Comment: The only solution is to `memset` the structure before first use. Then fill the members.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to implement pad_Foo() function

As standard compliant code the answer is **no**

From C11 draft n1570, 6.2.6 Representation of types:

> 6 When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type, including in a member object, the bytes of the object representation that correspond to **any padding bytes take unspeciﬁed values**. 51)

and

> 51) Thus, for example, structure assignment need not copy any padding bits.

So the standard clearly says: The value of padding can not be controlled.

On a particular system (platform, os, compiler) it may be possible. As an example from my system:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

struct s
{
  char c;
  int n;
};

void dump_struct(struct s * p)
{
  unsigned char * u = (unsigned char *)p;
  for (size_t i=0; i < sizeof *p; ++i) printf("%02x ", u[i]);
  printf("\n");
}

int main(){
  printf("sizeof(struct s)=%zu sizeof(char)=%zu sizeof(int)=%zu padding=%zu\n",
         sizeof(struct s), 
         sizeof(char), 
         sizeof(int), 
         sizeof(struct s) - sizeof(char) - sizeof(int));

  struct s sa;
  memset(&sa, 'A', sizeof sa);
  sa.c = '8';
  sa.n = 42;
  dump_struct(&sa);

  struct s sb;
  memset(&sb, 'B', sizeof sa);
  sb.c = '8';
  sb.n = 42;
  dump_struct(&sb);
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof(struct s)=8 sizeof(char)=1 sizeof(int)=4 padding=3
38 41 41 41 2a 00 00 00
38 42 42 42 2a 00 00 00
   ^^^^^^^^
    notice
```

So on my system the `memset` did write the padding bytes but on other systems you may see different behavior.

Adding code like this to `main`:

```
  unsigned char * u = (unsigned char *)&sb.c;
  u += sizeof sb.c;
  while(u < (unsigned char *)&sb.n)
  {
    *u = 'C';
    ++u;
  }
  dump_struct(&sb);
```

will print the extra line:

```
38 43 43 43 2a 00 00 00
```

So again - on my specific system - the padding was changed.

Comment: on any RAM instance of the struct, you can ALWAYS call `memset()` to initialize the memory before setting the individual fields within the struct